# Linux recover deleted directory

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, nfs, file-recovery

I had a directory named foo in my linux server. home/foo
I also had a file named foo.tgz in home directory.
I issued an extract of foo.tgz from home directory and the tar file had a directory named foo in it. So the directory home/foo got overwritten. Can I recover the old home/foo directory.

Comment: if the file system is journalling then it is possible to recover because new contents do not overwrite the old ones. Related link: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1411007.html

Comment: thanks. let me check with my sys admin

Comment: @AdityaKumar if a system doesn't have JFS, what other possible options do we have for recovery?

Comment: If there is no journalling then contents would either be over-written, or if not there is only one way (search heuristically the complete disk). There are some software (at least on windows) which search for deleted files. Search for one. hth

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. It wasn't overwritten though, their contents were merged.

Comment: this was on the server. So will the system admin be able to recover the old directory?

Comment: thats sad :( But anyway thanks for the quick reply. I had to manually edit some files to get back the old version. Took me 20 mins. But its better than waiting eternally hoping I would be able to recover.